# Check is data in field a valid JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have text field (varchar) in column which can be just text or some JSON.
How I can extract all fields where value is JSON and skip text?

Comment: check this answer by @a_horse_with_no_name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30187851/2275388

Comment: Advice: Fix the real problem and use different columns for different data types.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use an ISJSON built in function to test against the column value.

It will return 0 or 1. You can use it in where clause.

Comment: There is no `isjson()` function in Postgres

Comment: Sorry didn’t realize it’s for PosgresSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Using the function [`is_valid_json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30187851/2275388), provided by @a_horse_with_no_name ...

```
create or replace function is_valid_json(p_json text) returns boolean
as $$
begin
  return (p_json::json is not null);
exception 
  when others then
     return false;  
end; $$ language plpgsql immutable;
```

... you can filter your records before extracting the json elements, e.g.

Data sample

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (txt text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('no json'),('{"foo": "bar"}'),('no json');
```

Filtering valid json objects and extracting keys with [`json_object_keys`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT json_object_keys(txt::json) FROM t
  WHERE is_valid_json(txt)) q;

 json_object_keys 
------------------
 foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with PostgreSQL 16, there is the IS JSON predicate from standard SQL:

```
WHERE col IS JSON
```

See also: https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/is-json