# django custom function for filter query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've a field in my model called, `test_data = models.TextField(...)`, and the model is called `MyOrm`

and this `test_data` contains data which is actually string, some holds JSON data, and some reference to blob-url.

Now I'm trying to streamline my data. So I want to filter all the `MyOrm` object whose `test_data` ain't JSON.

I'm just storing/trying to store some meta-data along with url, then I will convert them.

Can anyone suggest me a way to do so??

pseudocode:

```
select all my-orm where is_not_json(my-orm.test-data)
```

Comment: If you're open to a schema change to do this, maybe consider using a JSON field type instead of `TextField`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no database function for this that I'm aware of. You can define your own, but then this is more database programming.

I think you have no other option than to enumerate over the `MyOrm` model objects, and check if you can JSON decode these, with:

```
import json

for item in MyOrm.objects.all():
    try:
        json.loads(item.test_data)
    except ValueError:
        # is invalid JSON, process
        # …
        pass
```

or if memory might be a problem, you can work with [**`.iterator(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator):

```
import json

for item in MyOrm.objects.all().iterator():
    try:
        json.loads(item.test_data)
    except ValueError:
        # is invalid JSON, process
        # …
        pass
```

Comment: `object.all()` maybe takes a ton of memory... the server i'm running it, it's a 4gb server...  can you suggest some efficient way? And also provide some link to that database programming you mentioned?

Comment: @Danial: see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187554/how-can-i-verify-in-postgresql-that-json-is-valid

Comment: @Danial: if memory is an issue, you can work with `.iterator()` to process the items in batches.