# Convert text column to jsonb in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a column `products` in a table `test` which is of type of `text` in the below format:

```
 [{"is_bulk_product": false, "rate": 0, "subtotal": 7.17, "qty": 2, "tax": 0.90}]
```

It is an array with nested dictionary values. When I tried to alter the column using this:

```
alter table test alter COLUMN products type jsonb using products::jsonb;
```

I get below error:

```
ERROR:  22P02: invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Character with value 0x09 must be escaped.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...some_id": 2613, "qty": 2, "upc": "1234...
LOCATION:  json_lex_string, json.c:789
Time: 57000.237 ms (00:57.000)
```

how can we make sure the json is valid before altering the column ?

Thank You

Comment: Check the first function mentioned here to validate a single json-string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187554/how-can-i-verify-in-postgresql-that-json-is-valid
Select all rows of the table and send the column you want to validate through this function, then you will see which rows are invalid. How you repair them.. is up to you.
Btw, your example has a comma to much.

Answer (score 2):

Your written JSON string is correct, so this SQL code execute without exception:

```
select '[{"is_bulk_product": false, "rate": 0, "subtotal": 7.17, "qty": 2, "tax": 0.90}]'::jsonb
```

Maybe the table has an incorrect JSON format in other records. You can firstly check this by selecting data, example:

```
select products::jsonb from test;
```

And you have incorrect syntax on your SQL code, you can cast `products` field to `JSONB` but not a `test`, `test` is your table name:

```
alter table test 
alter COLUMN products type jsonb using products::jsonb;
```

Comment: corrected the SQL statement, thank you

Comment: does the `text` column needs to have same keys in all the records to convert it to `jsonb` ? this column has varying fields

Comment: @DevBabai No, it's json, every object stands on its own; there is no "document schema" or something